# How to limit the memory used for each process of a certain binary?

Tags: linux, memory, limit

I have a process which is part of standalone, non-service executable.

The process in question spawns *thousands* of co-processes under a single binary. I'd like to limit the memory usage of processes spawned by this binary to a certain amount per process (~10M ea.).

Here are the requirements:

- The processes must be run under the current user
- The current user must be able to run other processes without memory limits
- The number of processes which should have the memory restriction fluctuates
- The limit should only apply to the given binary.

I notice there are other questions like mine, but they don't answer this question because they don't follow my requirements, Namely-

- They set the limits per process, not per binary
- They suggest creating a new user to run this binary in
- They provide solutions which do not work in modern Linux

Given the above requirements, how can one limit the memory usage per process which is using a given binary file?

Comment: Read `man bash`, about `ulimit`. You can run something in another process by putting `&` ar the end of the command. Again `man bash`.

Comment: @waltinator I'm not sure what your point is. I don't start 1000s of processes from a binary, another program does.

Comment: I'm not sure if [`cgrulesengd`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/cgrulesengd) with [`cgrules.conf`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/cgrules.conf) is still supported with `systemd`, haven't used it for a long time, but I did use it few years ago for similar purposes.

Comment: If not, how about creating a wrapper for your binary? Begin with `mv <bin> <bin>.exe`, than create a shell script instead of <bin> that runs `ulimit` and then `exec <bin>.exe "$@"`? It's an ugly workaround, if you update the package of your binary it might get overridden, but that's the only idea I could think of.